# ASP regular expression only allow numbers bigin with either 7 o 8

Tags: asp.net, regex

I need a regular expressin in asp.net , that will check my  account number field that only allows numbers that begins with a 7 or a 8.

Comment: No. I have no idea about this kind of regular expression . But I did some kind of regular expression for validating date, phone numbers.

Comment: What is the format of your account number? In other words, does it have a fixed length or does it have to be in a range?

Comment: Have 14 digit account number ( ex: 0123467-8954142).

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect your new format, which I assume should begin with a 7 or 8 even though that example does not.

Comment: Is the "-" charcter required or optional?

Comment: my regular expression for checking the account number with 14 didgit is (\d{7}[\-]\d{7}). it is working.  Also I made another one for checking the first digit as either 7 or 8 : ((?:7|8)\d{7}[\-]\d{7}). It wont working. I also tried ((7|8)\d{7}[\-]\d{7}).

Answer (score 1):

*[Edit]* This will work for your given case.  I have tested it in RegexBuddy.

```
^(?:7|8)\d{6}-\d{7}
```

Comment: what is this regular expression means ?

Comment: It means: a string that begins with a 7 or an 8, followed by 6 numbers, a dash, and then followed by 7 numbers. You can ignore the "?:", as that is merely a way of saying, "I don't want to capture anything!" (since normally, things enclosed in parentheses are captured).  @danseery's not trying to capture, only trying to group the "or" statement (`|`).  My ever-so-slightly simpler solution is posted as well, but I think you should give this guy the credit.

Comment: @acheong87 Well said!  I could have probably explained it better but I think you've done a good job of that.

Comment: I tried ^[7|8]\d{6}[\-]\d{7} and it is working for me for my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can try liks this (partial example)

```
^(7|8)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^[78][0-9]*
```

Expression should start with 7 or eight, then have 0 or more numbers.

Comment: But I see the original question has changed so this only solves part of the problem...

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Regex.IsMatch Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch.aspx)

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(AccountNumber, @"^[7-8]+$"))
```

Also, it will be helpful for you to go through these articles

[Regular Expression Basic Syntax Reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)

[Learn how to write a Regular Expression](http://geekswithblogs.net/brcraju/archive/2003/10/23/235.aspx)

Comment: As it stands, this only matches numbers entirely consisting of 7's and 8's.

Comment: Doesn't match the criteria: "that will check my account number field that only allows numbers that begins with a 7 or a 8."

Comment: I tried ^[7|8]\d{6}[\-]\d{7} and it is working for me for my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Exact solution to your 14-digit format:

```
^[78]\d{6}-\d{7}$
```

Answer (score -2):

you can try this one; I'm padding my answer here to go over the 130 character minimum length imposed by stack overflow

```
^[7-8]+$
```

Comment: You're right, the 130 character limit is just a stupid for-the-sake-of-it rule that you should ignore and work around when needed.

Comment: That only makes sure that the string starts with 7 or 8. I would assume that since this is an "account number" the rest of the string should also be numerical, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Furthermore this answer as it stands only matches numbers entirely consisting of 7's and 8's.